# Plotting an elliptical arc in TikZ with minimal additional packages and as simple as possible functions

Tags: plot

[image]

I have the above output from Mathematica that I would like to reproduce exactly in LaTeX, but I am just beginning with TikZ and do not understand the huge layers of code that are presented in other questions with similarly shaped elliptical arcs.

For that reason, I am not particularly interested in advanced packages, but if there is a package that allows me to do it using just the polar equation I will accept it as a solution.

I tried polar plotting but TikZ just breaks arbitrarily when I put in the polar form of the curve and for some reason ignores the square root.

Comment: Hi Jack, please help us to help you: if you put the code that didn't work for you in a form  a M(N)WE  we can try to see what happens. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @Rmano I tried the following line:
\draw [thick,color=black,domain=1:89,samples=200,smooth] plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x,radius= {sqrt(1-0.9800139176438553*cos(\x)*cos(\x))});
But it just renders a rotated semicircle (The angles are not the ones I am after this was just the initial test run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% 7/90*180=14
% -1/7*180=-25.71428571
% 6/7*180=154.2857143
  \draw
    [thick,color=black,domain=-25.71428571:154.2857143,samples=200,smooth]
 plot (xy polar cs:angle=\x,
        radius=
          {1/sqrt(1-0.9800139176438553*cos(\x-14)*cos(\x-14))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

TikZ's `cos` and `sin` use degrees per default.

Comment: how can I shift the curve along the x and y axes? I need it to align with something else that already exists.

Comment: `\draw[...,xshift=1cm, yshift=-1cm]`